# Call external rest API while processing Kafka stream in consumer end

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

Let us discuss a situation.

Consumer received a Kafka Stream , the Message in the stream needs to be enriched and validated based on some Validator Micro service and Enricher API call. also it persisted the Message into the DB.

Flow is like that - 
Kafka Stream consumer -> each message -> Call Rule Validator Rest API -> Call Enrich API -> Save to DB via Persistence REST API.

As all the REST calls are synchronous and rest calls are sequential before calling final Persistence  Micro service API.

Obviously Kafka Stream consumer gets high throughput messages.

How to achieve this via coding ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use REST.

If you have complete control over each piece of the pipeline, use Kafka Streams Processor API to get the pre-database output between 3 intermediate topics, then use Kafka Connect to sink to the database.

This will scale to much better loads than your REST APIs can handle

If you don't have control, you would have to make a task/request queue topic from which the next API call would be getting requests from another consumer and must wait until the first API response came from the one before